# Apple to reject any apps that access UDIDs,don’t support Retina, iPhone 5 displays?

Tags: ios, ios4, appstore-approval

Got news from [TNW](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/03/21/after-a-year-of-warnings-apple-will-no-longer-accept-any-apps-that-use-udids-as-of-may-1st/), which states, "`Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6."`

My question is quite simple, how about **OLDER APPS** that have been released before May 1st and do access UDIDs? Also, what if the app doesn't support retina display? Do they remove it from the App Store?. If so, I am afraid of hearing **YES**.

Comment: It says 'no longer accept NEW apps or app UPDATES', nothing about it being retroactive. Here's to hoping.

Comment: They are going to ask the developer to have them update their apps, but won't remove them from the app store. This is what my friend told me, but I will confirm about this

Answer (score 3):

They will not remove older Apps but its better to Update it with new rules like if it doesn't have retina support than it'll not useful for the retina iPhone & in current scenario Majority of users using retina iPhones only so its good to update the Application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Its very bad that apple not giving permission to access UDIDs, but there are some work arounds. Check out the [link](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)

Whatever, apple wont remove any app from appstore which is already reviewed by them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so if Apple need to remove the current app that recently access UUID it takes time to review before remove them out.