# iOS app including Facebook SDK rejected because of advertisingIdentifier

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, app-store

We got rejected twice now by Apple saying the advertisingIdentifier is still in our app but we don't show ads. We are not showing ads in our app, but we need the Facebook SDK.

So far I can only find two posts here on stackoverflow about this - but both don't solve the problem for me. Anyone else having this problem? The only option that I see now is to completely remove Facebook SDK until Facebook has an update. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574680/app-rejected-because-of-advertisingidentifier-in-facebook-sdk-and-flurry-sdk

Comment: Yes, but we got rejected again.

Comment: What else are you using? Any other frameworks which happen to use `advertisingIdentifier`?

Comment: When I do a "grep -r advertisingIdentifier ." on my project, I can find the advertisingIdentifier at multiple positions inside the SDK. Same for for "$ grep -r ASIdentifierManager ."

Comment: Clearly, those calls need to be removed/commented out. See that you do not mess up any working code in your project while doing this :)

Comment: You are only allowed to use the advertisingIdentifier for advertising. If you use it for anything else you will get rejected. We recently had this problem using the Mixpanel SDK.

Comment: Yep, thats clear, but why is it inside the Facebook SDK?

Comment: This is a question for you to ask Facebook developer support, not a programming question.