# Does Facebook 3.13 SDK resolves the app rejection because of advertisingIdentifier due to Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, app-store

My app was rejected before 20 days saying it has an advertisingIdentifier. I searched on google and came across with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574680/app-rejected-because-of-advertisingidentifier-in-facebook-sdk-and-flurry-sdk). I made appropriate changes and now my app is live on the app store, but I am not getting any facebook logs after doing this. Is there anything which I have missed out?

I also want to know whether the new facebook sdk 3.13 resolves the same issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anybody have solution of this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook iOs SDk 3.13 still does not fix the IDFA issue.
You can get the source code from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk , instead of the compiled framework. Just deleting the framework and pasting in the source code should do it.

Go to FBUtility.m and modify this method:

```
+ (NSString *)advertiserID {
    NSString *advertiserID = nil;
    Class ASIdentifierManagerClass = [FBDynamicFrameworkLoader loadClass:@"ASIdentifierManager" withFramework:@"AdSupport"];
    if ([ASIdentifierManagerClass class]) {
        ASIdentifierManager *manager = [ASIdentifierManagerClass sharedManager];
        advertiserID = [[manager advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
    }
    return advertiserID;
}
```

to

```
+ (NSString *)advertiserID {
   return @"";
}
```

Build your own framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done this but I am unable to get the log on fb after this. Do you know how to solve it?