# Improper Advertising Identifier Usage error on validating archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, lldb

I got below error after validating app through Xcode5.

> Improper Advertising Identifier Usage. Your app contains the Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not respecting the Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS.

I know there are already SO questions for this issue. But I could not solve my issue even after going through them.

My app does not display ad neither it has any ad network library.

I tried removing `AdSupport.framework` from project and it gives below errors :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBUtility.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I think this post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574680/app-rejected-because-of-advertisingidentifier-in-facebook-sdk-and-flurry-sdk