# App uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality

Tags: ios, facebook, appstore-approval, ads

My app has been rejected due to following reason:

**We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines[..]**

It looks like there's a issue with some library I included and to spot the offending library I followed the suggestion from this [stack-over-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489097/my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re)

In terminal

```
grep -r advertisingIdentifier .
```

And this is what I get back:

```
./Pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK/src/Core/FBUtility.m: advertiserID = [[manager advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];

./Pods/Quantcast-Measure/Quantcast-iOS-Measurement/QuantcastMeasurement.m: NSUUID* uuid = [manager advertisingIdentifier];
```

So it looks like there's a issue in the pods i have included.
I also check and I DO NOT include the AdSupport Framework, so how do I fix the issue?
Should I go and change manually the offending methods as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574680/app-rejected-because-of-advertisingidentifier-in-facebook-sdk-and-flurry-sdk)?

But what happen if I'm gonna update the pods later on?
thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Still no luck. How did you solve it? In my case it was FB SDK.

Comment: What I did is checking where in the Facebook API Code there was a reference to the advertisingIdentifier (grep -r advertisingIdentifier .) and commented it out.
The other solution is obviously as you suggested in your answer. =)

Comment: Concerning your use of the Quantcast SDK, it does not require usage of the IDFA. You do not have to change the SDK's code to prevent it using IDFA, you just simply do not link the AdSupport framework. The latest podspec for the Quantcast SDK does not by default link AdSupport framework.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if your issue was solved.. But this is what helped me fix the issue as I was using FB SDK and no third party ads. On my original submit I checked the first option saying Ads are served when they were not.

- Apple rejects it for using IDFA and select the First check box only if you are using third party apps to display the Ads. Do not check it if you are using iAd.
  *
- When submitting the app in iTunes Connect make sure you answer this question right "Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?"

  - Say Yes only if you use third party Ads or Facebook
  - else even if you use iAds just say No as iAds don’t use IDFA.
  - If you are Facebook, say Yes and select option 2 “Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement”.
  - Do not check the first option unless you are using third party ad tools like admob, google ads etc.
  - Never used the third option so far.
  - Make sure you check check the Limit Ad Tracking setting in iOS checkbox.