# Appstore Rejection: ASIdentifierManager

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, google-analytics, admob

I uploaded and got approved games using iOS Admob SDK on appstore in JAN'14 using `libGoogleAdMobAds.a`. These games does not have Google Analytics integrated.
I am using latest sdk version `GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0`

Recently I uploaded the app having Google Analytics and Admob with `(libGoogleAdMobAds.a,libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a)` and it got rejected because of the same reason mentioned here from apple ['my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489097/my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re)

Now, when I checked removing the static lib for Analytics `(libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a)` and AdSupport.framework, I found that the admob lib `(libGoogleAdMobAds.a)` is also referring to `ASIdentifierManager` and it want me to ad AdSupport for compilation.

My Question now is, if I keep only Admob static lib, would it be approved (which I think as my other games got approved in JAN'14 which were only having Admob) or apple has changed the review guidelines very-very recently and now we are not able to use Admob via its static lib?? OR Apple will approve the same and it was only related to the Analatics issue. The problem in re-trying is I waited 10 days to get my application "in review" and finally got rejected and It would be a long time again for me to keep waiting after a try (I hope every developer can understand this notion of "waiting for review" state).

Comment: You can always request for `expedited review` to apple for your app. They will approve it immediately.

Comment: they have guidelines for `expedited review` which does not cover such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally even after removing `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and waiting for another 9 days the app got rejected due to presence of `ASIdentifierManager` so anyways this concludes that we cannot submit app having admob to apple now.