# My app was just rejected for Ad Support Framework While using Revmob in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, revmob

I got mail from itunesconnect that my app that is using revmob has been rejected with the reason.

> We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not
>   include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the
>   iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store
>   Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License
>   Agreement states:
>
> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have
>   contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier,
>   and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user
>   resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine,
>   correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly,
>   the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the
>   reset Advertising Identifier."
>
> Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager,
>   or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd
>   implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd
>   support.
>
> Please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to
>   remove any instances of:
>
> class: ASIdentifierManager selector: advertisingIdentifier framework:
>   AdSupport.framework
>
> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please
>   remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have
>   included ad functionality.
>
> To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For
>   information on the “nm” tool, open a terminal window and enter, “man
>   nm.”

I need Ad Support framework for Revmob. Can anyone please help me to find out solution for this.

I have checked these Questions on Stackoverflow

[Question 1][My app was just rejected for using the Ad support framework. Which library is responsible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489097/my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re)

and [Question 2]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583311/ios-app-rejected-for-including-specific-function-in-the-adsupport-framework

But didn't find solution for this.

Comment: Apple clearly suggests if you are using any third party library then you need to mention in before you submit your app. Did you follow that?

Answer (score 1):

The reply from Apple itself gives you the solution. Use nm tool to find the Ad identifiers. Use grep command in the terminal to check for the advertising identifiers.

Also as you are using "revmob", http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html,they have clearly mentioned to select "YES" for using IDFA. Screenshot attached below.

[image: Check dis]

Comment: I have selected that. But still app got rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has stricter review guidelines that every one has to follow. From the response that Apple gave you, it seems that you are using Ad library that don't stick to Apple guidelines. From my perspective, most of the Ad library providers keep updating their frameworks as and when Apple reviews for Advertising changes. Find out from "revmob" team if they removed dependency on using "Advertising Identifier".

Also during app submission there'e a check box related to "Advertising". Did you provide appropriate value there?