# iOS Advertising Identifier PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have an app that was rejected form the iTune store for:

> We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does
>   not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of
>   the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App
>   Store Review Guidelines.

I have not put iAds in my app at all. I used PhoneGap Build to create the app. My code config.xml is:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro" version="5.0.0">
  <name>Beer Portfolio</name>
  <description>Know Your Beer</description>
  <author href="http://www.beerportfolio.glass" email="">Mike</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>

  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  - lower 4s -->
<icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />

<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch - 5-5s -->
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPhone6-6+ -->
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Are you using native Google Analytics SDK by any chance?

Comment: I am not using Google Analytics. I am using Flurry analytics though

Comment: That could be the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489097/my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re

Comment: Thanks, just removed Flurry. Going to be a week or so before I know if it works.