# iOS app was rejected for using “Advertising Identifier” PLA 3.3.12

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am using only Webtrends iOS SDK only not any AdSupport framework.
But apple was rejected my iOS app and got response from apple support team.

> We found that your app uses the Advertising Identifier but does not
>   include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the
>   Apple Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App
>   Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the Apple Developer Program License
>   Agreement states:
>
> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have
>   contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier,
>   and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising
>   Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user
>   resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine,
>   correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly,
>   the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the
>   reset Advertising Identifier."
>
> Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager,
>   or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd
>   implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd
>   support.
>
> If your app is serving ads, please:
>
> - Ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed all previous versions of your app
>     prior to testing
> - Provide us the steps to locate ads in your app
>
> If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any
>   third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:
>
> class: ASIdentifierManager selector: advertisingIdentifier framework:
>   AdSupport.framework
>
> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please
>   remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have
>   included ad functionality.
>
> To help locate the Advertising Identifier, use the “nm” tool. For
>   information on the “nm” tool, please see the nm man page.
>
> If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to
>   search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line
>   tools. The "strings" tool lists the methods that the library calls,
>   and "otool -ov" will list the Objective-C class structures and their
>   defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides.

Please suggest me to use mn tool to check AdSupport framework used in my app or not and If exist then How to remove it.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489097/my-app-was-just-rejected-for-using-the-ad-support-framework-which-library-is-re) thread

Comment: I have followed this link and used grep -r advertisingIdentifier . command but not got any response.

Comment: Thanks @Vin grep -r advertisingIdentifier . command is working . Can you suggest me how to use mn tool for this.